# Etymology of "plática"

Tags: etimología

DRAE doesn't say anything beyond that it comes from Latin. Wiktionary doesn't give even that. I even tried a bunch of other resources but nothing came out. Yes, I know it comes from Latin but I would love to see if anyone has anything more than that. I want to understand where the Latin *platica* came from and what it meant.

Comment: I case it helps, nobody uses "plática" in Spain. This is one of those words who suffers from regional differences.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help much. I know the word belongs more in Mexico than elsewhere. It's the etymology that I'm after.

Comment: I can't find a latin definition for _platĭca_ nor _platica_. I found a reference to a term _platicus_ (http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=start&lookup=platic&lang=la), but can't find a definition of that term. Internet is so incomplete. I wonder where did the RAE find that etimology.

Comment: @Diego It is used extensively in certain SA countries, especially Mexico. The term suffer is really pejorative in your sentence....

Comment: Aqui está la mejor explicación y no pude copiarla. Viene del griego en primer lugar http://etimologias.dechile.net/?platicar

Comment: @Lambie He aquí el texto del enlace que mencionaste: «El verbo **platicar** se deriva de plática. En España siempre hemos entendido sobre todo por plática una charla o sermón de tono sencillo que da un cura o religioso, pero especialmente en América se emplea muchísimo plática y platicar con el valor de charlar; en España se usa algo menos con ese valor general. Plática viene del latín *platĭca*, pero esto no era un nombre, sino la forma femenina de un adjetivo que significaba elemental o rudimentario. …»

Comment: @tchrist How do you do that? Please. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie 
It's easiest just to save the page into a file on your own computer and then use a text editor to pull out the needed bits and use the mouse to then copypaste from your text editor. You may also be able to get at it via "View Source" or "Examine Elements" in your web browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that that Latin form of *plática* was not a noun originally, but the feminine form of and adjective, which meant *elemental* or *basic*. It seems that it was used in expressions like *sermo platicus*, which means basic or rudimentary conversation, and *disputatio platica*, which means *basic argument or discussion*. Finally it turned into a noun to define a chat.

[Relevant reference for the etymology of `platicar`.](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?platicar)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I found no sources that confirm me, are just class notes.

The word *plática* derived from *práctica* in the Latin sense of "practicus", ("practical", "active"), which is related to the Greek "praxis".

In the usual sense, "práctica" refers to something habitual exercise. But "plática" refers to what is ordinary, usual.

In that sense, *platicar* originally refers to talk about what would be ordinary, common, current.